# linker command faild with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a project with two target . This project contain two `.a` file. One of them is Zbar and the other one named `libLizarusKit.a`. I added this libraries to the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` of the target that I am trying to build but when I trying to build the project I see two errors.

One of the is:

```
    Searching 1 file for "MyProjectName"

<untitled 23>:
    1: Ld /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.app/MyProjectName normal armv7
    2      cd "/Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project"
    3      export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    4      export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    5:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/rad/Documents/GIT\ Repo/iOS-AP/iOS\ Main\ Project/Lizarus -L/Users/rad/Documents/Documents/Archive -LCodes/Asan -LPardakht -LiOS/iOS/Milestones/iOS-05052015- -Lacceptor -L& -LQR -Lreader/Lizarus -L/Users/rad/Downloads/asan/ZBarSDK -F/Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyProjectName.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lLizarusKit -lzbar -framework SystemConfiguration -liconv -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyProjectName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.app/MyProjectName
    6  
    7  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rad/Documents/Documents/Archive'
    .
   14  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lreader/Lizarus'
   15  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._responseData in:
   16:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   17      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   18  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._timer in:
   19:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   20      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   21  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._lefttime in:
   22:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   23      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   24  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._delegate in:
   25:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   26      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   27  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._connection in:
   28:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   29      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   30  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._request in:
   31:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   32      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   33  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._response in:
   34:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   35      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   36  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._hostName in:
   37:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   38      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   39  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._contentType in:
   40:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   41      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   42  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIConnection._timeout in:
   43:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   44      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   45  duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LIConnection in:
   46:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   47      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   48  duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LIConnection in:
   49:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIConnection.o
   50      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIConnection.o)
   51  duplicate symbol _mod in:
   52:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LICalendar.o
   53      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LICalendar.o)
   54  duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LICalendar in:
   55:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LICalendar.o
   56      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LICalendar.o)
   57  duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LICalendar in:
   58:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LICalendar.o
   59      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LICalendar.o)
   60  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController.readerView in:
   61:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   62      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   63  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController.trackingView in:
   64:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   65      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   66  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController._isQR in:
   67:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   68      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   69  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController.player in:
   70:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   71      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   72  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController._delegate in:
   73:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   74      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   75  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController.soundType in:
   76:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   77      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   78  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController.soundName in:
   79:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   80      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   81  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LIBarCodeViewController._cancelTitle in:
   82:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   83      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   84  duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LIBarCodeViewController in:
   85:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   86      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   87  duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LIBarCodeViewController in:
   88:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LIBarCodeViewController.o
   89      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LIBarCodeViewController.o)
   90  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LITextField._keyboardMode in:
   91:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITextField.o
   92      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITextField.o)
   93  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LITextField._errorMessage in:
   94:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITextField.o
   95      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITextField.o)
   96  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LITextField._required in:
   97:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITextField.o
   98      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITextField.o)
   99  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LITextField._maxlength in:
  100:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITextField.o
  101      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITextField.o)
  102  duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LITextField in:
  103:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITextField.o
  104      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITextField.o)
  105  duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LITextField in:
  106:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITextField.o
  107      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITextField.o)
  108  duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LITrackingView._isQR in:
  109:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITrackingView.o
  110      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITrackingView.o)
  111  duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LITrackingView in:
  112:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITrackingView.o
  113      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITrackingView.o)
  114  duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LITrackingView in:
  115:     /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LITrackingView.o
  116      /Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project/Lizarus/libLizarusKit.a(LITrackingView.o)
  117  duplicate symbol _zbar_parse_config in:

118 matches in 1 file
```

And the second one is:

```
    GenerateDSYMFile /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.app.dSYM /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.app/MyProjectName
    cd "/Users/rad/Documents/GIT Repo/iOS-AP/iOS Main Project"
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.app/MyProjectName -o /Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.app.dSYM

error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/rad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-hkppcarpbiarhyaklpydovlxcodl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyProjectName.app/MyProjectName": No such file or director
```

I read the codes and try to understandt them but I have no idea. Generally when we include a wrong file or add a bad import I saw this error but now I have no idea. Does some one can help me about this?

Comment: `7  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rad/Documents/Documents/Archive'
    .
   14  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lreader/Lizarus'`
 - this mean that u have problem in ur paths setting in BuildSettings

Comment: I can not find any path settings

Comment: What is the relationship between these two targets?

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. One of the classes in the LizarusKit.a have same name with the class I decelerated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Finally I found the problem. Some of the classes in the LizarusKit.a have same name with some class that I myself decelerated in the project

Answer (score 1):

Check the framework search paths in build settings. This error is most probably due to the path errors. May be you changed the path of some items. Check that first.